# Passing implementations by ref: cannot convert from 'Foo' to 'ref IFoo'

Tags: c#, interface, reference, argument-passing

Can someone explain to me why this is incorrect in C#:

```
namespace NamespaceA
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        public interface IInterfaceA
        {
            String Property
            {
                set;
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace NamespaceB
{
    public class ClassB
    {
        public class ImpA: NamespaceA.ClassA.IInterfaceA
        {
            private String mProperty;
            public String Property{ set{ mProperty = value; } }
        }
        public ClassB()
        {
            ImpA aImpA = new ImpA();
            foo(ref aImpA);
        }

        private void foo(ref NamespaceA.ClassA.IInterfaceA aIInterfaceA)
        {
            aIInterfaceA.Property = "SomeValue";
        }
    }
}
```

This will produce a compile error of:

> Error Argument 1: cannot convert from 'NamespaceB.ClassB.ImpA' to 'ref NamespaceA.ClassA.IInterfaceA'

It seems perfectly reasonable to want to modify the interface properties and call the interface functions from `foo()`.  If you remove the `ref` keyword, it compiles, but the changes you make in `foo()` are lost...

Comment: what? you don't need ref in order to manipulate properties from an object.

Comment: Have to agree with @HighCore - ref is totally unnecessary here.

Comment: I edit the title from *reference* to `ref`. C#, like Java and Python, passes objects using [*Call By Object Sharing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) semantics. This is unrelated to *Call by Reference* (which is what `ref` does). See the previous comments.

Answer (score 16):

As Karthik said, `ref` and `out` don't support object-oriented polymorphism. But you can use generics (a.k.a. *parametric* polymorphism) to achieve the same effect.

Try changing the signature of `foo` to:

```
private void foo<T>(ref T aIInterfaceA) 
    where T : NamespaceA.ClassA.IInterfaceA
{
    aIInterfaceA.Property = "SomeValue";

    // This assignment will be visible to the caller of foo
    aIInterfaceA = default(T);
}
```

**Bonus** — If you want, you can put a `new()` constraint on the type parameter `T` and then it even lets you call its default constructor:

```
private void foo<T>(ref T aIInterfaceA) 
    where T : NamespaceA.ClassA.IInterfaceA, new()
{
    aIInterfaceA.Property = "SomeValue";

    // This assignment will be visible to the caller of foo
    aIInterfaceA = new T();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no need to use the `ref` keyword there.

You're passing an instance of reference type as a parameter and you do not need to mark the argument as `ref` to be able to modify its state, here `Property` property. Just remove the `ref` keyword and it'll work as expected.

Secondly, just think it over. As soon as an instance of the interface is a reference type, `ref` parameter makes it possible to change the reference passed, so you theoretically can return an absolutely different implementation of this interface.

So, definetely there is no implicit cast from `IInterfaceA` to `ImpA`, while your code requires the one.